# How to pull from multiple lists to make a new directory

Tags: python, list, loops, csv

I'm trying to pull data from two different lists in order to make a new directory. But Python says that the second list `queue` is not defined when I try to run it.

```
import csv
import time
import os, sys
from datetime import date

queuelist = ['ONE']
yearlist = ['2013']

year = str(date.today().year)
month = str(date.today().month)

for year in yearlist and queue in queuelist:
    os.mkdirs('{0}\{1}'.format(queue,year))
```

Comment: `But Python says that the second list queue is not defined` - that's because, well, `queue` variable is not defined.

Comment: @akecxe thanks! that was one of my problems... slow morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want either a nested loop ...

```
for year in yearlist:
    for queue in queuelist:
        # ... to do stuff for every possible year/queue combination
```

or you want to [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) the two lists ...

```
for year, queue in zip(yearlist, queuelist):
    # ... to do stuff with year-queue pairs of same index
```

Comment: thank you, would I need to add another colon by `yearlist` too? For the nested loop

Comment: Absolutely, edited it.